# Keeping file location in HTML when dealing with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a really cool affect I'd like to apply to a series of images. However the file location is contained in the CSS but I'd like to move it to the HTML code. How can I do this. I the style sheet there are a lot of other components that may interfere with img tags. How best should I do it. Here is the CSS code:

```
.social-slide {
    background-image: url(/static/images/icons/profile.png);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.social-slide:hover {
    background-position: 0px -50px;
    -webkit-filter: invert(30%); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to, you can put it in `style` attribute, but it's generally not a good idea.

`<div class="social-slide" style="background-image:url('hai')></div>`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it works for one image, but other images lose their size. Should I force the size into the style tag within the HTML too? The images are boxed correctly but the images which are normally 256x256 appear full size ... i.e. I can only see a small portion of the image comstrained to 50px by 50px

Comment: I fixed with: background-size:contain;

Answer (score 2):

In your html file do:

```
<style>
.social-slide {
    background-image: url(path);
}
</style>
```

Or you can do inline styling, though not recommended.